# Line spacing is off with mobile size and text in a table. I need to allow word break and kerning to prevent words being smashed on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I have this website I did. [www.kaylaperkins.com](http://www.kaylaperkins.com)

It's fine but when you shrink your browser to view as mobile or use Google's Mobile Emulator, the text doesn't wrap by adding a new line, it's wraps long sentences over itself.

Here's a snippet of the HTML

```
                    <div class="col-lg-7 ml-3">
                        <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Kayla Perkins | Resume</h3>
                        <p>Click to <a href="content/kayla-perkins-resume-2020.pdf" target="_blank">download my resume</a>.  Click to expand sections of my online resume.</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header cardheader" id="headingOne">
                                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            <span class="tabs">Film work</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>

                                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <table class="resumetable">
                                            <tbody class="resbody">
                                                <tr class="resumeborder">
                                                    <th><strong>Film</strong></th>
                                                    <th><strong>Role</strong></th>
                                                    <th><strong>Production</strong></th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="clear-fix">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td class="clear-fix">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td class="clear-fix">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="resumecol1 resumecolgeneral">
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <p>A Promise to Alexis</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="resumecol2 resumecolgeneral">
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <p>Lead</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="resumecol3 resumecolgeneral">
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <p>Christopher Siaens Films</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="resumecol1">
                                                        <p>Weekend Cabin</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="resumecol2">
                                                        <p>Lead</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="resumecol3">
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <p>Magnum Caliber Films</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="resumecol1">
                                                        <p>Maura The Vampire Princess</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="resumecol2">
                                                        <p>Lead</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="resumecol3">
                                                        <br><br>
                                                        <p>Magnum Caliber Films</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
```

And the CSS for resumecol1, 2 and 3

```
    .resumecol1 {
        width: 300px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .resumecol2 {
        width: 90px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .resumecol3 {
        width: 210px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

I added an overall CSS styling but of course, none of that works.

```
.resumecolgeneral {
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
    word-break: keep-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: manual;
    -moz-hyphens: manual;
    -ms-hyphens: manual;
    hyphens: manual;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    line-break: loose;
    line-break: strict;
    text-wrap: balance;
}
```

I know it's a table but would switching to a div help the issue?  It was just an idea to use a table in this context.

Here are pics of the two cases:

Desktop
[image]

Mobile
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.
In `.resbody` you have given `line-height:2px;` so wraps long sentences over itself, you need to set `line-height:20px;` and remove unused `<br />` tag you added in `<td>`.

```
.resbody {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: So I did exactly what you said.  No joy!  Argh!

Comment: I was wrong! I did exactly what you said.  IT WORKS!